# oracle stored procedure generates larger numbers through hibernate than it does alone

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence-generators

We have a stored procedure that generates numbers for entry ids (`entry_id_seq`). With the following setting, the code generates a relatively large number than it is called with SQL directly.

For instance, the following code generates a number "11195215652" for id. But if I run `select entry_id_seq.NEXTVAL nv from dual`, it returns "32350910" which is a lot smaller.

```
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "seq",
sequenceName = "entry_id_seq")
public class SomeClassimplements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
```

I tried the suggestion below

```
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "seq",
sequenceName = "entry_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue= 1)
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: increment size cannot be less than 1
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.OptimizerFactory$LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.<init>(OptimizerFactory.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.configure(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:110)
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of hibernate are you using?  If < 3.5.3 then check this https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5230

It appears that it affects legacy generators with allocationSize = 1 configured with annotations.

Resolution: 1. configure to use new generators, 2.Upgrade, 3.patch your version manually.

Answer (score 0):

Per discussion on:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=973682

the solution is:
In the SequenceGenerator annotation, add `allocationSize = 1, initialValue= 1`

Comment: i tried additional parameters above, but got the following error.

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: increment size cannot be less than 1
 at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.OptimizerFactory$LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.<init>(OptimizerFactory.java:336)
 at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.configure(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:64)
 at org.hibernate.id.factory.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:110)